# "Printf not declared in this scope" mesmo com o uso de #include <stdio.h>

Tags: c, dev-c++

Por qual razão estou recebendo a mensagem de erro :

`[Error] 'prinft' was not declared in this scope`

relacionada a linha 22 do código abaixo, se a primeira coisa que fiz foi declarar:

`#include <stdio.h>`.

Estou utilizando o IDE Dev C++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float a,b,c;
    float delta;
    float raiz1;
    float raiz2;

    a = -1;

    b = 1;

    c = -2;

    delta = (b*b) - 4.0 * a * c;
    raiz1 = (- b + sqrt(delta)) / (2.0 * a);
    raiz2 = (- b - sqrt(delta)) / (2.0 * a);

    if (delta < 0){
        prinft("Não ha raizes reais");
    }
    else {
        printf("A primeira raiz e : %f \n\nA segunda raiz e : %f \n\n",raiz1,raiz2);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dentro de `stdio` existe `printf()` mas não `prinft()`, conforme o  erro determina. Quando ver uma mensagem de erro leia ela toda com atenção.

Comment: Facepalm! obrigado pela resposta!